# Connecting Janrain social login to AngularJS

Tags: java, angularjs, janrain

Please note that I am asking a conceptual rather than a specific question.

**The question**: Fundamentally, a java servlet receives a post from an external API and needs to tell AngularJS about it. What is the best way or, what are the main considerations in deciding the best way?

For background, my particular situation is with the Janrain social login API:

I want to use the Janrain social login with AngularJS. Following their examples I can successfully get all the way from AngularJS to Janrain and back to a java servlet which completes with a valid user profile. So that whole flow works.

Where I am stuck is how to get from the java servlet back to AngularJS. There seem to be several approaches such as:

1. Deploy the Janrain javascript client (janrain-init.js) and insert an event in AngularJS as in `janrain.events.onCaptureLoginSuccess.addHandler()` - except I have no idea where to find a copy of janrain-init.js (yes, I've looked).
2. Create a .jsp page as the return destination from Janrain, call java from the jsp page to swap the token for the profile and then somehow communicate the result to AngularJS. But how?
3. Keep the return destination as the java servlet and somehow send a notification to Angular. But how?

Thank you

**Update:** What I have learnt...
1. The best way is to have the API notify the browser that it has completed
2. Then get flow back to AngularJS as quickly as possible
3. From AngularJS call (using http) the Java servlets for any follow-up processing

That way the flow is determined by events only.

Comment: I think you need to clarify whether you are using "just" Janrain Social Login or are you using Janrain Social Login with Janrain Registration (aka "Capture").  The Social Login only "init.js" code is described on this page:
https://docs.janrain.com/social/implementing-sl/
In the section titled: "3. Get the Code"

Otherwise, if you are implementing Janrain Registration the process is covered here:  https://docs.janrain.com/registration/implementing/

You may need some help from whoever set up your account or you can contact: support.janrain.com

Comment: It is just Janrain Social Login. I finally made progress with the Janrain/Java/Angular challenge after looking at the source code on this page: http://janrain-solutions.appspot.com/socialLogin/client_side_validation